# Did George Washington‘s investment in the Ohio Company eventually turn a profit?

Tags: colonial-america, george-washington

The intent of some English and Virginia speculators (including two brothers of George Washington and Virginia Royal Governor Robert Dinwiddie) to open the Ohio Valley (then a French possession) to settlers, led to  [the creation of the Ohio Company](https://www.u-s-history.com/pages/h1173.html) in 1747, and eventually to the French and Indian War, thus sparking off [the Seven Years‘ War](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1877721?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents).

George Washington‘s active involvement in the early stages of the French and Indian War (Fort Necessity, Monongahela), following his [promotion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Washington)  by Dinwiddie in 1754 to lieutenant colonel and second-in-command of the 300-strong Virginia Regiment, is arguably difficult to extricate from  [his vested interests](https://www.mountvernon.org/george-washington/french-indian-war/ten-facts-about-george-washington-and-the-french-indian-war/#:%7E:text=Royal%20Governor%20Robert%20Dinwiddie%2C%20George,of%20the%20vast%20Ohio%20Valley.) in the Ohio Company.
What became of this speculative venture after the Treaty of Paris (1763)? Did Washington‘s bet pay out?

Comment: Please back up all non-trivial assertions with sources. You think 16-year-old George Washington had vested interests in the Ohio Company because......?

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I have added some (in my view relevant) sources.

Comment: You say that "intent of some English and Virginia speculators...led to the creation of the Ohio Company...and eventually to the French and Indian (and thus to the Seven Years‘) war." The ordinary meaning of those words is that this was the main cause. Can you defend that assertion or might the question be better worded? (The F&IW was the spark that lit the 7YW's fuse, but to suggest that it was the only available spark seems a stretch. My understanding is that the French and British were moving to war and the main question was "When?"))

Comment: You're right. I will try and rephrase the assertion.

Comment: @MarkOlson I read something in one of the books I got at Fort Necessity National Battlefield where a British diplomat addressed George Washington, referring to "this war you've started", referring to his actions at Jumonville Glen.